# Как записать число из строки в переменную

Tags: java, строки

Есть следующий код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Укажите дату рождения: ");
    String n = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

В консоли указываю дату рождения, например, ***`18 декабря`***, но мне нужно записать число в переменную `int`, а название месяца - в строку, чтобы потом сравнивать. Как разбить строку на число и строку, т.к. сейчас в переменной `n` строка? Вопрос простой но не могу понять что нужно использовать для этого, т.к. я только учусь. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно читать ввод по частям:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Укажите дату рождения: ");

        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int date = scanner.nextInt();
        final String month = scanner.next();

        System.out.println("Вы указали '" + date + "' '" + month + "'");
    }
}
```

Или же считать целиком и разрезать:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Укажите дату рождения: ");

        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final String[] tokens = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        final int date = Integer.decode(tokens[0]);
        final String month = tokens[1];

        System.out.println("Вы указали '" + date + "' '" + month + "'");
    }
}
```

А можно и с регулярными выражениями поиграть:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Укажите дату рождения: ");

        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final String line = scanner.nextLine();
        final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s(.+)").matcher(line);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            final int date = Integer.decode(matcher.group(1));
            final String month = matcher.group(2);

            System.out.println("Вы указали '" + date + "' '" + month + "'");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Неправильный ввод.");
        }
    }
}
```

---

***P.S.*** По хорошему, ещё и исключения неплохо бы отлавливать.

Comment: Спасибо! А метод next() возвращает следующий символ?

Comment: @Nevada Нет. Кусок введённой строки до разделителя. Разделитель можно узнать методом Scanner.delimiter и установить методом Scanner.useDelimiter.